# Wordpress Internal page links not working

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I moved my wordpress site from ipage Hosting to goDaddy hosting.
Site URL: [http://cyberbel.com/](https://web.archive.org/web/20151129083442/http://cyberbel.com:80/)

**Problem:**
Internal pages links in the header menu redirects to 404 Not Found error page.
Sample Internal Page link: [http://cyberbel.com/onlinegames/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150418111931/http://cyberbel.com:80/onlinegames/)

**Steps Tried:**

1. I created a new .hta file, and saved the permalinks settings. But .hta file is not getting updated or netiher getting created if the existing .hta file is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> try this,

i have faced such issue in client OS7 and i follow the below instruction and solved it out..

```
1. Give proper permission

2. enable the mod_rewrite
```

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)